# Kibana splits URL

Tags: logging, nginx, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm having an issue in Kibana 3.
I'm storing Nginx access log and need to show the top web requests.

I'm using logstash with this simple filter:

```
filter {
grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" ]
}}
```

In the elasticsearch results for one query seems alright:

```
root@elk01:~# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2014.11.11/nginx/6bf4PWmhQq6bV0T5YCwI5w?pretty
{
  "_index" : "logstash-2014.11.11",
  "_type" : "nginx",
  "_id" : "6bf4PWmhQq6bV0T5YCwI5w",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"message":"Nov 11 01:00:19 web09 ngxaccess: 178.178.178.178 - - [11/Nov/2014:01:00:10 +0100] \"GET /avatars/t/144402.jpg HTTP/1.1\" 200 7019 \"http://www.domain.com/fr\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53\"","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-11-11T00:00:20.249Z","type":"nginx","host":"elk01","path":"/var/log/HOSTS/10.10.10.10/access.log","timestamp":["Nov 11 01:00:19","11/Nov/2014:01:00:10 +0100"],"logsource":"web09","program":"ngxaccess","clientip":"178.178.178.178","ident":"-","auth":"-","verb":"GET","request":"/avatars/t/144402.jpg","httpversion":"1.1","response":"200","bytes":"7019","referrer":"\"http://www.domain.com/fr\"","agent":"\"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53\""}
}
```

And the mapping seems alright too:

```
root@elk01:~# curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2014.11.11/_mapping?pretty
...
"request" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
```

But in Kibana I have a splitted request field like in this example *avatars* and not */avatars/t/144402.jpg*.

What am I doing wrong?
Did someone already had this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Benoît

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everyone who has ever used elasticsearch for non-word data (e.g. log files) has faced this issue.

The field is being analyzed, as shown by your mapping.  Logstash tries to help you by creating the "raw" multi-field that is not analyzed.  In kibana, try referring to "request.raw".

Answer (score 0):

The .raw at the end of my field did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not populating the data via logstash or you don't have a raw field for whatever reason, you can create it like so (ES5):

```
curl -XPUT 'my-es:9200/my-index/_mapping/my-mapping' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"properties": {"request": {"type": "string", "fields": {"raw": { "type": "keyword"}}}}}'
```